# Пересечение объектов direct2d C++

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

впервые работаю с разработкой движка для игры, для этого выбрал direct2d и возник вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы точка не пересекалась с любыми другими объектами, какой наименее затратный для этого есть способ.
Пока что единственная идея, которую я нашёл - это хранить в векторе все координаты периметра объектов и по наименьшим расстояниям до них запрещать перемещение.

PS
Например, на поле есть несколько рандомно заданных объектов, и есть виртуальная точка, которая не должна в них попасть.

Comment: воз'мите box2d.

Comment: Можно также взять boost::geometry